# Gametime in Android

Tags: java, android

Is there a straight forward way to keep track of game time in Android (java)? For instance in order to keep movement fluid no matter what frame rate, I need to factor in the amount of time which has passed by since the last frame. This is pretty easy to do in XNA (since its all setup for you) but even without a game engine you can still use timeSpan in C#. I tried looking up timespan for java but it doesn't come up with much or then long hand. Is there an equivalent, short hand way of handling frame to frame timing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game logic should run in a separate thread that is independent of frame rate. Then when refreshing the screen you just draw the objects in their current state.

When you do need to be able to measure time, use SystemClock.elapsedRealTime

Answer (score 0):

Well there's the Handler class that allows you to run a thread with a certain delay.

```
postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)
```

You can use this to set a certain gametime for a thread.  Setting delayMillis here to 33 would be a little over 30 frames per second.  I'm pretty sure there are game libraries for Android out there, however, that will be more helpful for issues like these.

You could try to manually get the time inbetween each instance like so:

```
long lastTime = 0; 

Thread {

    if (lastTime != 0) 
        elapsedTime = System.getTimeMillis() - lastTime;

    lastTime = System.getTimeMillis;

}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I have to account for variable frame rates based on the device. If a device can push 60fps, then it should be able to move the object the same amount of pixels as a 30fps.

Comment: I updated it with a manual check, but I don't know of a straight forward solution. Sorry!